# Read.csv and manual input not resulting in same format

Tags: r, csv

I am reading a list of tickers into a list in R.  I'm passing it in manually, and then through a csv file.  As you can see, there output from the first command and the second command are completely different.

```
list_1<- c("ABC","DEF","XYZ")
list_2<-read.csv(paste0(pwd,"LIST.csv"), header=T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=F)

list_1
[1] "ABC"  "DEF"  "XYZ"

list_2
1 ABC
2 DEF
3 XYZ
```

I would like the result of list_2 to be the same as list_1, but I know I am making a dumb mistake here and am just not sure what the terminology I need to google is! Argh!

Any thoughts?  Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: Just use `list_2[,1]` or instead of `read.csv` use `scan`

Comment: Or `scan` instead.  `scan(paste0(pwd,"LIST.csv"), sep=",", what=character())` Or maybe `readLines("LIST.csv")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.csv` will read in a table, and the resulting structure is a data frame.
In this case, your data frame has only one column.
You can can extract that column like so:

> list_2 <- read.csv(...)[[1]]

Alternatively, `readLines(...)` if you know your file contains only a vector of strings.